# Eclipse close down suddenly

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I am using eclipse Juno for android programming but what is happening Eclipse getting close without saving my code suddenly i am sharing part of error-log throwing by eclipse

```
      #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f131d3382a1, pid=19624, tid=139722885666560
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f13bc008000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=19625, stack(0x00007f13c4e79000,0x00007f13c4f7a000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x00007f13bc6ec0d0, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000001, RDX=0x00007f13c4f98968
RSP=0x00007f13c4f772e0, RBP=0x00007f13be0a77c0, RSI=0x00007f13be0a77c0, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x00007f13be4c3750, R10=0x00007f13c4f76ec0, R11=0x00007f13c4f76fc0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000d879cdf0, R14=0x00007f13c4f773b8, R15=0x00007f13bc008000
RIP=0x00007f131d3382a1, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
       .
       .

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007f13bc6ec0d0 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007f13c4f98968: _rtld_global+0x908 in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at 0x00007f13c4d75000
RSP=0x00007f13c4f772e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f13bc008000
RBP=0x00007f13be0a77c0 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00007f13be0a77c0 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007f13be4c3750 is an unknown value
R10=0x00007f13c4f76ec0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f13bc008000
R11=0x00007f13c4f76fc0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f13bc008000
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000000d879cdf0 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
R14=0x00007f13c4f773b8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f13bc008000
R15=0x00007f13bc008000 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007f13c4e79000,0x00007f13c4f7a000],  sp=0x00007f13c4f772e0,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkit.WebKitGTK._soup_session_feature_detach(JJ)V+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkit.WebKitGTK.soup_session_feature_detach(JJ)V+9
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.WebKit.create(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+920
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+81
j  org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.html.BrowserInformationControl.isAvailable(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+12
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover$HoverControlCreator.doCreateInformationControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/IInformationControl;+18
j  org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractReusableInformationControlCreator.createInformationControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/IInformationControl;+20
```

and many more error log. What is happening here i am not able to understan. Any suggestion is really appreciated , i am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why this question down voted ? Is any body have explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below line in .ini file at end(eclipse/configuration/config.ini) and see if it works

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```